# show image when cursor placed over link\image (same image showing up on all links)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display images via mouseover, which is achieved with the javascript below and images\links with class="trigger". How each step works is detailed via comments in the code below. The issue is it only works properly for the first image\link, ie: span data-original="foobar.jpg", subsequent mouseovers all display the same image.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.trigger').mouseover(function() {
    // find our span
    var elem = $(this).siblings('span');

    // get our img url
    var src = elem.attr('data-original');

    // change span to img using the value from data-original
    elem.replaceWith('<img src="' + src + '" width="50%" height="50%" style="display:block;position:absolute;"/>');

  });

  $('.trigger').mouseout(function() {
    // find our span
    var elem = $(this).siblings('img');

    // get our img url
    var src = elem.attr('src');

    // change span to img using the value from data-original
    elem.replaceWith('<span data-original="' + src + '"></span>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/gotourl" class="trigger" target="_self"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Launcher" border="0"></a>
<span data-original="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=SPAN+1"></span>

<a href="/gotourl" class="trigger" target="_self"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Launcher" border="0"></a>
<span data-original="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=SPAN+2"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this using `next()` instead of `siblings()` :

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.trigger').mouseover(function() {
   // find our span
   var elem = $(this).next('span');

    // get our img url
   var src = elem.attr('data-original');

    // change span to img using the value from data-original
   elem.replaceWith('<img src="' + src + '" width="50%" height="50%" style="display:block;position:absolute;"/>');

  });

  $('.trigger').mouseout(function() {
   // find our span
   var elem = $(this).siblings('img');

    // get our img url
   var src = elem.attr('src');

    // change span to img using the value from data-original
   elem.replaceWith('<span data-original="'+src+'"></span>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="trigger" target="_self"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Launcher" border="0"></a>
<span data-original="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=SPAN+1"></span>

<a href="#" class="trigger" target="_self"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Launcher" border="0"></a>
<span data-original="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=SPAN+2"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.siblings()` selector will select EVERY span that is a sibling - meaning both.

Later, `elem.replaceWith(...)` will replace EVERY `elem` in the jQuery collection with that content.

The `elem` jQuery collection contains EVERY span. So...

The fix is to wrap the `<a><span>` combo in a `div` thus:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.trigger').mouseover(function() {
    // find our span
    var elem = $(this).siblings('span');

    // get our img url
    var src = elem.attr('data-original');

    // change span to img using the value from data-original
    elem.replaceWith('<img src="' + src + '" width="50%" height="50%" style="display:block;position:absolute;"/>');

  });

  $('.trigger').mouseout(function() {
    // find our span
    var elem = $(this).siblings('img');

    // get our img url
    var src = elem.attr('src');

    // change span to img using the value from data-original
    elem.replaceWith('<span data-original="' + src + '"></span>');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="/gotourl" class="trigger" target="_self"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Launcher" border="0"></a>
  <span data-original="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=SPAN+1"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="/gotourl" class="trigger" target="_self"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=Launcher" border="0"></a>
  <span data-original="https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=SPAN+2"></span>
</div>
```